# React useState: pushing a sub-array into an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am using function based component and am having trouble in pushing a subarray into a useState array.
my code is shown below. There is an array called **mode** coming from the **props** which i need to append it as a sub array of **more**

```
const ViewCharts = (props) =>{

//other codes

let [more,setMore] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(props.mode,' mode array')
        let temp = [...more,props.mode]
        console.log(temp, ': this will append to more')
        setMore(temp)
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(more,'after setting')
        },2000)
},[//some value])

}
```

when the **props.mode** has value **['top','bottom']** i expect **more** to have value of **[['top','bottom']]** and when next time if the **props.mode** is ['top'] i need **more** to have **[['top','bottom'],['top']]**. but this is what am getting when i run the above code.

["top"] mode array

["top"] : this will append to more"

[] : "*after setting*"

why the setMore is not adding array even when the temp is having the expected value.

Comment: Does use the prev state value fix your problem ? as it: edit setMore(temp) to setMore(prevMore=>([...prevMore,props.mode])) and don't use the temp variable anymore

Comment: are you familiar with [closures](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36)?

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly the `useState` variable will change value in the next render when you set it. You are trying to read the new `more` value in the same render you've changed it *(as you are reading it in the same effect you've set the value in)*, which will be `[]` the first time as that's how you initialised it.

Try creating a second `useEffect` with a `more` dependency to see if it gives you the value you want:

```js
// You can also just console.log() before the return, needing no `useEffect` to see if the value indeed changed.
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log('More: ', more);
}, [more]);
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#recap

> Line 9: When the user clicks, we call setCount with a new value. React will then re-render the Example component, passing the new count value to it.

I would suggest reading the hooks API to better understand how they work.